# Trying to send Message TO Twitch Chat

Tags: python-3.x, irc, twitch

I have the bot already set up to where it reacts to certain commands like using text-to-speak and playing mp3 clips when chat uses the commands, however, I can not figure out how to get to get it to respond by SENDING BACK a message INTO chat when, say, someone says "Hello Fuzzy".  I get the **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**.  I am obviously doing something wrong but other bots that I have checked out are all coded in a different way and trying not to have to re-do the whole thing. Thanks for any help offered!!!

```
# Config portion
import socket
import time
import re
import pyttsx3
import soundfx


HOST = "irc.chat.twitch.tv"  # the twitch irc server
PORT = 6667  # always use port 6667
NICK = "fuzzybottgaming"  # twitch username, lowercase
PASS = "oauth:[]"  # your twitch OAuth token
CHAN = "#[my channel]"  # the channel you want to join

# Message Rate
RATE = (20 / 30)  # messages per second

#BANN HAMMER
PATT = [
    r"swear",
    # ...
    r"some_pattern"
    ]

# bot.py portion
# Network functions go here

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(PASS).encode("utf-8"))
s.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(NICK).encode("utf-8"))
s.send("JOIN {}\r\n".format(CHAN).encode("utf-8"))





def chat(sock, msg):
    '''
    Send a chat message to the server.
    sock -- the socket over which to send the message
    msg -- the message to be sent
    '''
    sock.send("PRIVMSG #{} :{}".format(CHAN, msg))


def ban(sock, user):
    '''
    Ban a user from the current channel.
    sock -- the socket over which to send the ban command
    user -- the user to be banned
    '''
    chat(sock, ".ban {}".format(user))


def timeout(sock, user, secs=10):
    '''
    Time out a user for a set period of time
    sock -- the socket over which to send the timeout command
    user -- the user to be timed out
    secs -- the length of the timeout in seconds (default 600)
    '''
    chat(sock, ".timeout {}".format(user, secs))





# Make sure you prefix the quotes with an 'r'
CHAT_MSG = re.compile(r"^:\w+!\w+@\w+\.tmi\.twitch\.tv PRIVMSG #\w+ :")


while True:
    response = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    print(response)
    if response == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
       s.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
       print("Pong")
    else:
        username = re.search(r"\w+", response).group(0)  # return the entire 
        match
        message = CHAT_MSG.sub("", response)
        print(username + ": " + message)

    if 'hello fuzzy' in message:
        s.send("Hello to you too " + username).encode("utf-8")

    #TTS and MP3 sound effects section taken out#
        for pattern in PATT:
            if re.match(pattern,message):
                ban(s, username)
                break
    time.sleep(1 / RATE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out where I went wrong.  I had an extra '#' for CHAN, in def chat I needed to add '\r\n' and '.encode("utf-8")'